# Ionic 3 Image mapping issue

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to use 'image mapping' with shape poly or other solution to build an app, based on image handled functionality.

I have tried it using in Ionic 3 and worked fine in Browsers, but under Android it does not.

Is there any solution to solve it?

This picture and functionality would the part and parcel of my app so it is indispensable to create clickable areas on image.

UPDATE:
This is the 9's tooth  shape from 32 :) I have an universal denture image with the normal 32 tooth shape. My goal is to transform the image to a 32 clickable tooth, with their own shape.
It is important to know, on which tooth the user clicked, because I want to give for the clicked tooth a colored background. This works on browser under Ionic3 fine, but builded to android not.

'<'img src="denture.png" usemap="#image-map"'>'

'<'map name="image-map"'>'

'<'area target="_blank" alt="Tooth9" title="Tooth9" href="Tooth" coords="407,93,421,89,434,87,447,90,458,91,468,94,478,103,480,112,476,125,471,135,467,146,462,153,453,158,441,158,428,152,419,141,412,129,406,118,401,109,403,98" shape="poly"'>'

'<'area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="" shape="0"'>'

'<'/map'>'

Comment: Before read your codes, we can just pray to you

Comment: Hi, I attached a concrete sample code with the description what I want.